# Is there a way to disable dependabot from the YAML config?

Tags: github, yaml, dependabot

Github has dependabot integrated into the repo I'm working on. I have a dependabot YAML (.yml) config file already that controls many aspects of how it runs. Is there an option that I can add to this file that will disable dependabot?

I tried getting a straight answer from the documenation, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this via the dependabot config file, you can try

```
ignore:
       - dependency-name: "*"
```

But I don't see the point in this. If you don't want to use dependabot, just disable it. First - by removing the dependabot configuration.

But it will still open PRs for security updates. To disable this, go to the GitHub repository settings and click [disable Dependabot security updates](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-security-updates/configuring-dependabot-security-updates#enabling-or-disabling-dependabot-security-updates-for-an-individual-repository)